# How to extend VSCode code completion with a third-party JavaScript library

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In my projects I use a third-party JavaScript library. I cannot import it explicitly in my code, this library is provided by JavaScript engine at runtime. 
I want to make coding easier by extending VSCode Intellisense by this library on all my project. I have a JavaScript file with function signatures of this library.
What are the ways to do this? I already tried:

1. write `/// <reference path=''>` to file in project. It works but 
   it’s not very convenient to write it in all files.
2. use jsconfig.json file. This method did not work for me. Maybe I did
   something wrong.
3. create extension with `vscode.codeCompletionProvider`. It works but VSCode does not perceive the input code as an object, interpreting it like text.
   That's why after dot symbol VSCode offers other text that I entered 
   as part of the program and my completion item located below this
   text.

I have the following directory structure

```
.
├── project1
│   ├── ...
│   └── modules
├── project2/
│   ├── ...
│   └── modules
├── projectN/
│   ├── ...
│   └── modules
├── types
│   └── lib.js (file that I want to add to Intellisense)
├── .gitignore
└── jsconfig.json
```

And I tried the following file contents of `jsconfig.json`:

```
{
   "include": ["types/**/*"] // (also tried ["types/lib.js"] and ["types/**/*.js"])
}
```

Please help to deal with this issue. Maybe I'm missing something. Is there a way to expand the Intellisense? Thanks

Comment: Can you share the jsconfig you tried?

Comment: @MattBierner yes, I added it to question body

Comment: Not sure I understand your particular scenario, but have you tried the instructions listed here? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/jsconfig#_using-webpack-aliases

Comment: @Jhecht this didn't work for me (or maybe I do something wrong). I can't import library explicitly and I haven't webpack in all projects